# How to handle touch event in render queue in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, grand-central-dispatch

I just found out that SceneKit's rendering happens in render queue, which is a non-main serial queue. This is different from SpriteKit which handles rendering in main thread.

Now I am having a race condition because of this. My touch control is in main thread, and the per-frame update function is in render thread. Both will be setting position for a SCNNode.

Looks like the render queue is private (i could be wrong) so I can't dispatch touch calls to it. So I am wondering how to handle the touch in render thread?

Answer (score 0):

Touch comes from UIViewController, GameControl is a class where I move objects around with timers.  I didn't use SpriteKit only so I can't comment on that, but it sounded like some example code would help...

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
...

```
func update(vTime: TimeInterval)
    {
        switch data.gameState
        {
        case .staging:
                timersOn()
                setMode(vState: .run)
                gameStateManager.run()
                gameStateManager.isStagingActive = true
            }
            break
        case .nextWave:
            if(gameStateManager.isNextWaveActive == false)
            {
                if(gameControl.nextWave() == false)
                {
                    gameStateManager.endGame()
                }
                else
                {
                    gameControl.resumeGame()
                    setMode(vState: .run)
                    gameStateManager.run()
                }
                gameStateManager.isNextWaveActive = true
            }
            break
        case .run, .defenseAdd, .defenseUpgrade:
            gameControl.updateTime(vTime: vTime)
            break
}

@objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        
        let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: gameScene)
        
        if(data.isAirStrikeModeOn == true)
        {
            let projectedPoint = gameScene.projectPoint(SCNVector3(0, 0, 0))
            let scenePoint = gameScene.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(location.x, location.y, CGFloat(projectedPoint.z)))
            gameControl.airStrike(position: scenePoint)
        }
        else
        {
            let hitResults = gameScene.hitTest(location, options: hitTestOptions)
            for vHit in hitResults
            {
                if(vHit.node.name?.prefix(5) == "Panel")
                {
                    // May have selected an invalid panel or auto upgrade was on
                    if(gameControl.selectPanel(vPanel: vHit.node.name!) == false) { return }
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }

extension GameViewController: SCNSceneRendererDelegate
{
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)
    {
        update(vTime: time)
    }
}
```

Timers are in GameControl - move objects, set nodes, etc.

Per comments, here is additional information:

SceneKit creates a transaction automatically whenever you modify the objects in a scene graph. This transaction groups any additional changes you make from the same thread during the current iteration of that thread’s run loop. When the run loop next iterates, SceneKit automatically commits the transaction, atomically applying all changes made during the transaction to the presentation scene graph (that is, the, version of the scene graph currently being displayed).

This post [31700071] provides insight into the question of what you can/should do in the main thread and how it impacts the render loop.

Comment: This will have race condition because `renderer` and `handleTap` are running on different threads

Comment: It's always possible I could have done it wrong...  but I've used this structure for several games.  I built a simulator to play the games and have run tests non stop for up to a full week without stopping.  I also tracked live crashes (none) and FPS stats.  I use DispatchQueue.main.async (to turn timers on) so that the timers run in the main thread.  GameControl {} does all node manipulation.

Comment: this is not thread safe. it's open to race condition and may even crash.

Comment: Great - please post your answer so we can all learn something about how this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the answer - I am also looking for a solution that's thread safe

Comment: Please see edit - I think the code I supplied is the correct way to handle tap, timers, and threads.  You handle tap in the UI, then do your object manipulation in the render loop... IE - my GameControl class.

Comment: @Voltan let's say in touch handler you want to set position, how would you dispatch to the render thread

Comment: gameControl.airStrike(position: scenePoint) -> that moves the position of my airStrikeNode to the surface where you touched it.

Comment: That's not thread safe - you set the position in the main thread, but it's also read and updated in render thread.

Comment: Per this post [31700071] Nodes/geometry aren't actually added on the main thread even if that's where you do it. Scenekit does not render on the main thread.  The inverse - If I want to tell the UI to update a button from the render loop, then you have to call DispatchQueue.main.async - or it will def crash it.

Comment: That does not prevent the race... unless you update in main thread using a closure API (something like `update(_ oldPos: CGPoint)`), which is no the case. otherwise reading it directly will definitely cause race condition

Comment: Ok, sorry I could not help you.  Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, I looked at a lot of example code including SKScene and ARKit and some objective C code just out of curiosity but I didn't find examples where someone did some kind of closure over this threading issue.  I'm no expert on apple threads, but it's pretty surprising that I didn't have any crashes reported from Fabric or any FPS problems.  These games were NOT a huge success with a gadzillion players or anything, but surely someone would have crashed it easily if this is the case.  I'm at a loss to understand that.  Hope you figure it out.